# How to create a GUI in Java that runs another language in the background?

Tags: java, user-interface, functional-programming, background-process

So for a hackathon I want to use this domain-specific language, Cryptol, in order to create an encryption system. However, I want a GUI for said system.

I have no idea how I could write a GUI in Java that run Cryptol in the background. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: if there is no java api for the language you want to use, you will need to use  something like https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html to start the other tool

Comment: Notice a python-cryptol bridge exists, which might have some ideas you could borrow if you're willing to undertake a larger project.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question, however, let me take a stabe.

There are multiple ways to create a GUI in Java (JavaFX, JSF, JSP, Swing to name a few). Without any experience, I would say JavaFX is the easiest to get started with. But that is completely opinion based of course.

When there is no standard API (library) to interact with Cryptol, you should create a rudimentary API for yourself. How? That completely depends on which functionalities from Cryptol you need and how Cryptol exposes it's interfaces.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sorry for the ambiguity, I'm a bit of a beginner... So, let's say I just want to pipe input txt to Cryptol, how difficult would this be? Let's say my GUI has a text box, and when a user inputs a text box it does the equivalent of running a Cryptol function on the command line >>function "textbox input"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ProcessBuilder class in java to execute programs through the command line. Essentially, ProcessBuilder allows you to execute programs as if you were to execute them in the command line by passing a string to the ProcessBuilder constructor. You can then read the response from ProcessBuilder to view the output of your other programs. Here is the documentation for Process Builder -> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html